# items array is empty when trying to add items to cart

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai9R8.png)so I am trying to add items to the cart but the array is empty, I cant find the problem. I think the backend which is node.js is working correctly because when I add item to cart by typing the url in the browser http://localhost:4000/cart/5dd7668f33c21d811b74f403, it is increasing the cart quantity and redirecting to http://localhost:4000/cart/ but when I navigate to http://localhost:3000/cart/ there is nothing displayed in the browser and the items array is empty when I inspect it using chrome developers tools.I think the frontend react and the backend are not linked correctly. I have added the pictures of it for further clarification and here is the code of my application.
Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let Book = require("./models/bookModel");
var session = require("express-session");
var MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
var flash = require("connect-flash");

const port = 4000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
    cookie: { maxAge: 180 * 60 * 1000 }
  })
);


app.use(flash());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/books", { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", function() {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully..");
});

const bookRoutes = express.Router();
app.use("/books", bookRoutes);
const cartRoutes = express.Router();
app.use("/cart", cartRoutes);

bookRoutes.route("/").get(function(req, res) {
  Book.find(function(err, books) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json(books);
    }
  });
});

bookRoutes.route("/:id").get(function(req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id;
  Book.findById(id, function(err, book) {
    res.json(book);
  });
});

cartRoutes.route("/").get(function(req, res) {
  var cart = req.session.cart;
  var displayCart = { items: [], total: 0 };
  var total = 0;

  for (var item in cart) {
    displayCart.items.push(cart[item]);
    total += cart[item].qty * cart[item].price;
  }
  displayCart.total = total;

  return res.json(displayCart);
});

cartRoutes.route("/:id").get(function(req, res) {
  req.session.cart = req.session.cart || {};
  var cart = req.session.cart;
  let id = req.params.id;
  Book.findById(id, function(err, book) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (cart[id]) {
      cart[id].qty++;
    } else {
      cart[id] = {
        item: book._id,
        title: book.title,
        price: book.price,
        qty: 1
      };
    }
    console.log(req.session.cart);
    res.redirect("/cart");
  });
});
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on Port: " + port);
});
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import BooksList from "./components/book-list.component.js";
import BookDetails from "./components/book-details.component.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Navigation from "./components/navigation.component";
import Cart from "./components/cart1.component";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Navigation></Navigation>

        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={() => (
            <div className="container">
              <BooksList></BooksList>
            </div>
          )}
        ></Route>
        <Route path="/books/:id" exact component={BookDetails}></Route>
        <Route path="/cart" exact component={Cart}></Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

book-details.componentjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../css/styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default class BookDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      book: [],
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/books/" + this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ book: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  AddToCart = e => {
    let id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id");
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/cart/${id}`).then(() => {
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/cart";
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { book, quantity } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col sm-4">
            <img src={`./images/${book.cover}`}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="col sm-8">
            <h2>{book.title}</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Category: {book.category}</li>
              <li>Author: {book.author}</li>
            </ul>
            <p className="button blue">${book.price}</p>
            <p>{book.description}</p>
            <button id={book._id} onClick={this.AddToCart}>
              Add to Cart
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

cart1.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import CartItem from "./cart1-item.component.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { throws } from "assert";

export default class Cart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/cart/")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          items: response.data.items
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  checkItems() {
    return this.state.items.map((currItem, i) => {
      return <CartItem book={currItem} key={i}></CartItem>;
    });
  }

  Calculate = item => {
    return item.qty * item.price;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">{this.checkItems()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

cart-tem1.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const CartItem = props => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>{props.book.title}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartItem;
```

I have been stuck on this for almost a week now and tried all I could to make it work but to no avail, any help would be immensely appreciated

[chromedevelopertools[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGbpL.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug everything without trying it, but I'm pretty sure you have an issue with the session.

Sessions are implemented by cookies (things your browser sends on every request), and they depend on the domain for security reasons. They don't play well with Single Page Applications.

When you go to port :4000 the browser sends the cookies for you, but on port :3000, axios should send the cookies from that other domain. Try adding this config in your calls:

> axios.get('xxx', {withCredentials: true});

It ~might work, though I feel you'll need to do some extra work somewhere else to initialize that cookie in the first place.

If you're going for the SPAs (which is popular choice nowadays) I'd recommend not using sessions and try to make your server 'Stateless'. It'll have other benefits too. Instead of that cookie thing, you'd need to implement something like Oauth or JWT (I recommend Jwt if you are getting started). That has enough keywords for you to google! :)

Comment: hey, could you guide me through the jwt thing. I am relatively new to express and react. It would be really helpful.

Comment: It's not a short process, try to find some good tutorial (I don't know your background so as to recommend you one). Something like this maybe? https://medium.com/swlh/jwt-authentication-authorization-in-nodejs-express-mongodb-rest-apis-2019-ad14ec818122 That's the backend, you then need to send the token you generate on every request from the frontend